# r use of rms ols function with multiple objects and confidence intervals

Tags: r, dplyr, confidence-interval, tidy, rms

This example below uses the `lm` function and `tidy(..., conf.int=TRUE)` easily generates summary estimates and C.I for multiple model objects.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

mtcars %>%
  gather(predictor, measure, -mpg) %>%
  group_by(predictor) %>%
  do(tidy(lm(mpg ~ measure, .),conf.int=TRUE))
```

How do I generate similar output using `rms::ols` function ? `tidy` does not work on `ols` so is there a way to tweak the output from `ols` function to include C.I from multiple model objects ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask someone to write a `tidy` method for `ols` ... ???

Comment: @BenBolker, its about time that someone did that.

Comment: PS I think the "group_by/do()" approach is now deprecated in favour of "nest_by/map/unnest" approaches ... ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a bare-bones/stripped-down version of `tidy.ols`. It has many limitations (see below), but should do what you want ...

```r
tidy.ols <- function(x, ...) {
   se <- sqrt(diag(x$var)) 
   rdf <- x$stats["n"] - x$stats["d.f."] - 1
   cc <- coef(x)
   ci <- confint(x)
   tibble(term = names(cc),
          estimate = cc,
          std.error = se,
          statistic = cc/se,
          df = rdf,
          p.value = 2*pt(-abs(statistic), df = rdf),
          conf.low = ci[,1],
          conf.high = ci[,2])
}
mtcars %>%
  gather(predictor, measure, -mpg) %>%
  group_by(predictor) %>%
  do(tidy(ols(mpg ~ measure, .)))
```

### limitations

- ignores additional args without checking
- <del>haven't checked p-value calcs etc.</del>
- doesn't allow choice of confint or not, or setting conf level
- doesn't consider other possible bells and whistles of `ols` ...

It seems like support for `rms` objects has been discussed a lot on the `tidymodels/broom` GitHub site but everything there is stale ... I opened [an issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/broom/issues/1166) if anyone wants to chime in.

Comment: i just checked the `p values` and `C.I `from regular `tidy(lm(` vs `tidy.ols(ols` both appear similar, no difference, so looks good to me. Thanks Ben. Tidy including a wrapper for rms objects is my wishlist.